# Turn text after slash into variables with HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to use the text after the slash as variable.
exemple :

```
www.mydomain.com/client1
```

This is equivalent to

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php?customer=client1
```

I tried to use :

```
$customer = basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

But didn't work.

I think I have to do it in the .HTACCESS file or maybe using basename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to write `HTACCESS` for that

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /yourDirectory/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /yourDirectory/index.php [L]
</ifmodule>
```

The above htaccess points all the URLs to `index.php`

After adding this content into HTACCESS, you can use your PHP code to access your `basename()` URI under `index.php`.